# Perform arithmetic operations from operators defined as strings

Tags: java, algorithm, operators

I have been recently trying to find a solution to this problem, but so far I have been unsuccessful.

I was thinking of doing the operation `a # b # c # d`, where a, b, c and d are predefined constants and # can take the value of any of the following operators '+', '-', '*', '/'.

I was thinking of finding all possible (distinct) solutions of `a # b # c # d` for all the operators replacement in #.

I was thinking of a logic on the following lines:

```
// Global declaration of an array list
static ArrayList<Double> values;

String[] chars = {"+", "-", "*", "/"};
int totalSolutions = 0;
values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i=0; i<chars.length; i++){
   for (int j=0; j<chars.length; j++){
      for (int k=0; k<chars.length; k++){
         if (isNew(a chars[i] b chars[j] c chars[k] d)) totalSolutions += 1;
      }
   }
}
public static boolean isNew(double value){
   if (values.contains(value)) return false;
   else values.add(value);
   return true;
}
```

isNew() is a function which just checks if the new solution obtained is different from all the previous solutions obtained.

I have not found out ways of applying the operator between the operands.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: will your implementation ignore precedence of the operation, if a + b * c, will it calculate b*c first?

Comment: I'd prefer an implementation with precedence of operations. But without it will do for now.

Comment: can you post code for **isNew** function? I dont think its doing what its supposed to do

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/37712870/1090562 It might give you some thoughs.

Comment: In your code I only see the counting of the number of solutions. The obvious answer would be 4^3. (It is more complex, if you want to know the different results of the expression for given `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`.) Would this be enough for you or do you want to know the solutions, too?

Comment: Hint: make a `switch()` statement over the operator character.

Comment: I've updated the isNew() function

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad, I'm counting distinct solutions. So the answer would be lesser than or equal to 4^3

Comment: @SalvadorDali, Thanks, that post did give me some idea.

Comment: Yes, but *distinct solutions*  is ambiguous: Is "1+0+3+4" a distinct solution from "1-0+3+4"? It is a *distinct expression* having the *same result*. So is the "distinct" related to the expression or the result?

Comment: The distinct solution is based on the result. In your case it is distinct since the result is distinct.

Comment: Eh, in my case it is not distinct, because the result is not distinct (always 8). But I understood, what you mean. However, I think that you have to write a little parser and calculator.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't see that. Yes, the solutions are not distinct in this case.

Comment: Off Topic, I am quite sure I have seen 1 or 2 posts with exact question and good answers on SO, I just cannot find it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from JDK1.6 you can use built-in Javascript engine to evaluate this expression for you .

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    String expression = "100+200/100*2";
    System.out.println(engine.eval(expression));
    } 
}
```

So you can use it to calculate the expression according to operators precedence rules.

Also If you need just the count of solutions , it might be easier to use `TreeSet` then print the size of the set at the end.

Here is a full explanation :

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
        int a = 100;
        int b = 200;
        int c = 300;
        int d = 100;
        String[] chars = {"+", "-", "*", "/"};
        try {
            TreeSet<String> set = new TreeSet<>();
        for (int i=0; i<chars.length; i++){
           for (int j=0; j<chars.length; j++){
                for (int k=0; k<chars.length; k++){
                    String expression = a+chars[i]+b+chars[j]+c+chars[k]+d;
                         set.add(String.valueOf(engine.eval(expression)));
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(set.size());
        } catch (ScriptException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Ahmed, that did let me evaluate the expression while following operator precedence.